# A good counter faction to Ninja-Zombies

Tags: smash-up

I just played Smash up with the **second edition** and the first as ***Bear Cavalry-tricksters*** against my Dad who played as          **Ninja Zombies** And he kicked my butt,

I'm aware that there are **counter factions**, like say Tricksters do awful against Ghosts since Ghosts are all about Discarding cards, and Tricksters keep making you discard.

Ninja Zombies seem to have good synergy with each other which makes it quite clever, since Zombies keep coming back from the dead when Ninjas kill everything.

Is there any **counter factions** towards them all?

Comment: When you say they're countering each other, do you in fact mean they have good synergy (kinda the opposite)?

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 3):

I think that one of the best pairs to face **ninja-zombies** would actually be more unconventional. I have found that **robot-wizards** do extremely well against that match for a few reasons. 
The first is that they don't focus on killing your opponent's minions at all. This means that they focus entirely on their own thing and don't waste cards killing your opponent's zombies.
The second reason is that they build themselves up *a lot*. If your opponent manages to kill something (seeing stars), then you still have a base full of **microbots** and **chronomages** to score easily.
The final reason is that **ninja-zombies** are very inconsistent. They cant draw as much and portions of their hand will always be useless. This makes cards like **tech center** and **winds of change** very useful because you can always have the cards you need.

I don't know what your preffered play-style is, but **robot-wizards** works very well against most factions. You just need to watch out for pirates and trickster because of base blocking and large removal cards.

Comment: Robots are quite probably the most powerful faction in the game by a long way. They're a combo powerhouse. You're right in that they work exceptionally well with wizards, because wizards are an enabler deck, drawing lots of cards and setting the robots up to combo reliably and repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's one correct answer here, but the first two factions that come to mind for me:

- **Pirates:** This faction has the ability to take out large numbers of minions at a time. Since you may be facing lots of minions coming back from the dead, clearing out an entire base in one action could be useful. Also, Pirates can move minions around from base to base pretty efficiently. You can use this to spread out forces, or bring your own to scoring bases, or pull enemies to a base to score it for yourself.
- **Aliens:** The Aliens faction, similar to pirates, can move minions around. Unlike the Pirates, they can send minions back into a player's hand *OR* to the bottom of their deck. This is most helpful against Zombies because they can no longer play those minions from the discard pile.